# TableView is not showing row headers properly

Tags: android, tableview

I have used this [tableview](https://github.com/evrencoskun/TableView) in my android app. The problem i have is, the table doesn't show row headers properly. This is the table:

[image: Table]

There are `5 rows` and i have added `5 RowHeader` items, but the `first item` is expanded to all `row headers`.

This is the code of initializing row headers:

```
// set row header
List<RowHeader> rowHeaders = new ArrayList<>();
for (PersianDate day : dataset.keySet())
    rowHeaders.add(new RowHeader(Integer.toString(day.getDayOfMonth())));

mTableAdapter.setRowHeaderItems(rowHeaders);
```

in the adapter:

```
@Override
public void onBindRowHeaderViewHolder(@NonNull AbstractViewHolder holder, @Nullable RowHeader rowHeaderItemModel, int rowPosition) {
    RowHeader rowHeader = rowHeaderItemModel;

    // Get the holder to update row header item text
    MyRowHeaderViewHolder rowHeaderViewHolder = (MyRowHeaderViewHolder) holder;
    rowHeaderViewHolder.cell_textview.setText(rowHeader.getData());

    // It is necessary to remeasure itself.
    rowHeaderViewHolder.cell_textview.getLayoutParams().width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    rowHeaderViewHolder.cell_textview.requestLayout();
}
```

Do you know what is the problem?

Comment: Are you sure that rowHeaders has 5 items?

Comment: Of course. Debugged several times

Answer (score 0):

In row header xml file, set height & width for your rowHeaderViewHolder.cell_textview